# Can't select html text

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have run into a peculiar problem.

Some HTML text on my page becomes unselectable and its anchor descendants are not recognised when hovered (Tested in chrome).

You have to fulfill certain requirements to cause it to happen. Here is my example page:

http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/personal-and-people-development/

If you reduce the browser window width to smaller than 520px (So my `@media` css kicks in) you are no longer able to highlight or select a link in the main body of text.

Can anyone see what is causing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<div id="sidebar>"` is overlapping the `#main div` when the page size is reduced.

Add `z-index:100` to `#main`

```
#main {
padding-top: 0.5em;
z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, a `z-index` of 1 is sufficient.

Answer (score 9):

> user-select: text !important;

this can help u thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you reduce the browser window width to smaller than 520px, you `#sidebar` is falling over your `#main` what makes it impossible to select something out of the `#sidebar`. Put a z-index on your `#main`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who found this page researching a similar problem, if you use the HTML5 boilerplate from html5boilerplate.com, some of the CSS included can cause your content text over a white background to not show as highlighted when you select it. Specifically the CSS for "::selection" should be adjusted or removed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a padding for an element, and then you position another element absolute inside the padding of the second one, you will have this problem.

```
#container .list li .list-left-left {
            width: 120px;
            position: absolute;
            padding-left: 10px;
        }

        #container .list li .list-left {
            width: 240px;
            position: absolute;
            padding-left: 165px; 
        }
```

The solution is to use margin-left not padding left.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who have the problem with unability to mark text, check if someone didn't block this purposely using javascript, for example like that:

```
function disableselect(e) {return false}
document.onselectstart = new Function (return false)
document.onmousedown = disableselect
```

Answer (score 0):

I just met with this problem and I found out it was because I made an input forever focused.

Thus, check if your code have something like this. It interrupts other elements from being highlighted.

```
<input onblur="this.focus()" type="text" id="calInput" autofocus/>
```